# Google colab automatically change language

Tags: google-colaboratory

Every time i open colab cite, it changes language to non english

I checked that:

- My google account have english by default
- *google.com domain in cookie auto delete whitelist

Answer (score 3):

Go to Chrome -> Settings -> Advanced -> **make sure your preferred language (English) is on top of the list.**

just like [here](https://www.funzen.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/1572940143_442_How-to-change-the-Chrome-language-in-a-few-steps.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Google Chrome language settings.
Go to Chrome -> Settings -> Advanced -> Language and set it to English.